# Derivative of matrices involving transpose and inverse

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have an equation which looks like this:
$$Z = [{A(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}A^TB - B}]^T[{A(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}A^TB - B}]$$
Here,
$\lambda$ is scalar ($\lambda > 0$) and $I$ indenty matrix such that
$$\mathbf{\lambda I}=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 0\\
0 & \lambda\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
I want to find $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \lambda}$ in order to prove that if $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2$ then $Z_1 \geq Z_2$.

Here, is what I tried
$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \lambda} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} [{A(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}A^TB - B}]^T[{A(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}A^TB - B}]$

$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \lambda} = 2\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} [{A(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}A^TB - B}]$ ...($\frac{\partial X^TX}{\partial X}$ = 2X)

$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \lambda} = 2[\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} (A) * [(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}A^TB] + A[\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} (A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1} * (A^TB) + (A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1} * \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}A^TB]
 - \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}B]$

...($\frac{\partial MN}{\partial X}$ = MN' + M'N)

$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \lambda} = 2[0 * [(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}A^TB] + A[\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} (A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1} * (A^TB) + (A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1} * 0]- 0]$
...($\frac{\partial A}{\partial \lambda}$ = 0, $\frac{\partial B}{\partial \lambda}$ = 0, $\frac{\partial A^TB}{\partial \lambda}$ = 0)

$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \lambda} = 2A\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} (A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1} * (A^TB)$

$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \lambda} = -2A(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} (A^TA + \lambda I) * (A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}*(A^TB)$
...($\frac{\partial M^{-1}}{\partial X} = -M^{-1}M'M^{-1}$)

$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \lambda} = -2A(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}I(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}(A^TB)$
...($\frac{\partial (A^TA + \lambda I)}{\partial \lambda} = I$)

I am unsure of this answer since I expected the derivative to be positive so that the above statement/proof can be proved.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that you need to know here is that

$$\dfrac{d}{d\lambda}(A^TA+\lambda I)^{-1}=-(A^TA+\lambda I)^{-2}.$$

Therefore,

$$\dfrac{dZ}{d\lambda}=-[A(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-2}A^TB]^T[A(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}A^TB - B]-[A(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}A^TB - B]^TA(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-2}A^TB.$$

Expanding that yields

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\dfrac{dZ}{d\lambda}&=&2B^TA(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-2}A^TB-B^TA(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-2}A^TA(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}A^TB-B^TA(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}A^TA(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-2}A^TB\\
%
&=&2B^TA(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-2}A^TB-2B^TA(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-2}A^TB+2\lambda B^TA(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-3}A^TB\\
%
&=&2\lambda B^TA(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-3}A^TB
%
\end{array}
$$
which is positive semidefinite.

Comment: This step might be trivial. But can you elaborate more on the expansion step and what you did after? I am completely lost on what's happening.

Comment: Yes, I just added and subtracted $B^TA(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}\lambda(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-2}A^TB+B^TA(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-2}\lambda(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}A^TB$. Then, you can factor some terms and they simplify. Just write it down and do the calculations,

Comment: You can reduce the visual clutter by defining a new variable $(F)$
and using dots to denote derivatives
$$\eqalign{
F &= A(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}A^TB - B
  &\quad\implies\quad Z &= F^TF \\
\dot F &= -A(A^TA + \lambda I)^{-2}A^TB
  &\quad\implies\quad \dot Z &= \dot F^TF + F^T\dot F \\
}$$